# Python multiprocessing freeze fork-bomb

Tags: python, multiprocessing, fork, pyinstaller, cx-freeze

I have a nice simple Python script:

```
import multiprocessing


def foo():
    print('running foo')


def main():
    print('start')
    ctx = multiprocessing.get_context('spawn')

    p = ctx.Process(target=foo)
    p.start()
    p.join()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

It runs exactly as it should when called with the python interpreter:

```
$ python test.py
start
running foo
```

Attempting to freeze the script, on the other hand is far less nice.

Both

```
pyinstaller test.py
```

and

```
cxfreeze test.py
```

result in what is effectively a fork bomb:

```
$ ./dist/test/test
start
start
start
start
.
.
.
```

And watching in htop, we see that indeed many many processes are spawned and the machine very quickly locks up.

Changing the start method to `fork` instead of `spawn` does not result in a fork bomb.

```
ctx = multiprocessing.get_context('fork')
```

What is it about the freezing process that plays nicely with fork and not spawn? Can the freezing process be changed to allow spawn?

Comment: I suppose you're running Linux right?

Comment: there's a `freeze_support()` to call when freezing executables on windows. seems useless on Linux, though.

Comment: Yes, using Linux. For completeness I gave `freeze_support()` a shot anyway - no change.

Comment: normal as freeze_support is only required for windows. There's a slight difference between windows & linux in the multiprocessing module. default for linux is "fork", default for windows is "spawn". Sounds related to your issue.

Comment: I'm struggling to find a good description of the difference between `fork` and `spawn`, other than the differences in resources that are passed to the new process, as outlined in the docs.

Comment: Looks like a bug in the spawn support on non-Windows systems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to reproduce the problem with the [`Tools/freeze/freeze.py` script in the cpython repo](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Tools/freeze/freeze.py), so the problem is indeed deeper than cx_freeze or pyinstaller.

After some more digging I discovered that I'm not the only one having the problem - the following issue was opened about a month before I hit the problem:

https://bugs.python.org/issue32146

They have some ideas for fixes which hopefully will make it into a 3.7.x release.